# Access Azure database sync logs remotely

Tags: database, azure, synchronization

Any idea on how to access the logs from a db sync on Azure - without going through the portal?

I want to report on the sync from an external website (the website that is actually making use of the sync).

I checked the DataSync schema tables that the sync created in the database, and none of them seem to contain the logs.

Google also hasn't yielded any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's stored with the service itself, not in the databases. and as of the current release, there is no other way to access it other than thru the portal.

Comment: Thanks JuneT - any suggestions on how to report the status of the sync to the system?